# Simple update query is causing 'subquery returned more then one record error'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use following query:

```
UPDATE    HazardInjuryRegister
SET       Level2Account = 'Ambulance Operations'
WHERE     (Level2Account = 'Operations')
```

But I get the following error:

> < Subquery returned more then one value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is very confusing as it doesn't have subquery and it has worked on other tables. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:**
The code of the trigger on this table:

```
USE [xzxzxz(name of the DB)]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[HazardInjuryNearMissLastUpdated]    Script Date: 03/17/2021 14:15:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- SQL Server Syntax  
-- Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a 
-- table (DML Trigger on memory-optimized tables)  
--Drop TRIGGER [dbo].[HazardInjuryNearMissLastUpdated]
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HazardInjuryNearMissLastUpdated]
ON [dbo].[HazardInjuryRegister]   
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  
AS 
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @action as char(1);
    DECLARE @id as int;

    SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SET @action = 
                CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                    ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
                END
        END
    ELSE 
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN; -- Nothing updated or inserted.
    

    if @Action = 'U'
        BEGIN
            Set @id = (Select [ID] From deleted);

            Update HazardInjuryRegister 
            Set DateUpdated = GETDATE()
            Where ID = @id;
        END
End
```

Comment: What have you done to diagnose it so far? Has your table maybe a trigger? Have you checked the execution plan? Can you post table and sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Its called a trigger... this is one of their downsides if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Sounds like a trigger that assumes that a DML statement can only ever effect 1 row; that assumption is wrong.

Comment: If the only REAL action your trigger takes is to update **UPDATED** rows with the current date and time, then why does it have all that <is insert, is update, is delete> logic? And for that matter, why is it defined for insert and delete statements if it does nothing for them?

Answer (score 1):

This statement cannot generate such an error.  There are no subqueries.  Well, it *might* be able to if `HazardInjuryRegister` is an updatable view, but I'm guessing you are not using such a beast.

So, the culprit is a trigger on the table.  It is a malformed trigger -- which is simple to write in SQL Server.

In particular, the trigger uses views called `inserted` and `deleted`.  These contain information about the rows that are changing.  People who do not know better often assume that these views have only one row.  This is a bug waiting to happen.  And you are seeing this bug because your code is updating more than one row.

You need to fix the trigger.  Or find the person who wrote it and have that person debug it.

EDIT:

The trigger is broken.  The line is causing the problem:

```
        Set @id = (Select [ID] From deleted);
```

It assumes that `deleted` has one row.  The correct syntax for this piece is:

```
    BEGIN
        Update HazardInjuryRegister 
            Set DateUpdated = GETDATE()
            Where ID in (Select [ID] From deleted);
    END;
```

I would suggest a code review of the code for this trigger -- and for any other triggers that that developer wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Gordon. Contacting the previous developer might not be possible.

I'll copy the code of the trigger below. Is it necessary for such a simple query I want to do? Because I can't comment it out / remove the code, execute queries and revert it. I can only delete trigger file itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was really helpful. We just need to see how to handle triggers from now on.